# How to get only unique row result

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have complex join query ,

```
Select a.date, b.Name, d.description
 FROM tableA  as a
 INNER JOIN (SELECT Name, MAX(Time) as lastSentTime FROM tableA 
 GROUP BY Name) b ON a.Name = omh.Name AND b.lastSentTime = b.setTime
 INNER JOIN tableD as d ON d.Id = a.id 
 INNER JOIN tableE as e ON e.Id = d.id
 INNER JOIN tableF as f ON f.Id = a.id
 WHERE a.status = 'FAILED' AND a.Class = 'Secondary' AND a.marks = e.marks
```

which will return data as

```
Date    Name    Discription 
1/2/16  Test    I am testing
1/2/16  Test    I am testing
1/2/16  Test1   I am testing1
1/2/16  Test1   I am testing1
```

I need result as

```
 Date    Name    Discription 
1/2/16  Test     I am testing
1/2/16  Test1    I am testing1
```

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT a.date, b.Name, d.description`..., however you may want to investigate why you're getting duplicates in the first place.

Comment: I am agree with @JoachimIsaksson, you must investigate why the select is returning duplicate results first. Distinct is the resource of the poor man: in this case is not correct to use it because it is masking a poor join in some part of the select

Comment: this question could be better understood if you post some examples of the content of the tables. However, try to remove some of the tables until the duplicates dissapear: when they do, the las table removed is the culprit

Answer (score 0):

Try DISTINCT

```
Select DISTINCT a.date, b.Name, d.description
 FROM tableA  as a
 INNER JOIN (SELECT Name, MAX(Time) as lastSentTime FROM tableA 
 GROUP BY Name) b ON a.Name = omh.Name AND b.lastSentTime = b.setTime
 INNER JOIN tableD as d ON d.Id = a.id 
 INNER JOIN tableE as e ON e.Id = d.id
 INNER JOIN tableF as f ON f.Id = a.id
 WHERE a.status = 'FAILED' AND a.Class = 'Secondary' AND a.marks = e.marks
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an entirely different approach is what you need. The join to the subquery seems very strange. Also one of your join predicates was in there where clause instead of the join.

```
with SortedResults as
(
    Select a.date
        , b.Name
        , d.description
        , ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by b.Name order by a.date desc) as RowNum
    FROM tableA  as a
    INNER JOIN tableD as d ON d.Id = a.id 
    INNER JOIN tableE as e ON e.Id = d.id AND a.marks = e.marks 
    INNER JOIN tableF as f ON f.Id = a.id
    WHERE a.status = 'FAILED' 
        AND a.Class = 'Secondary' 
)

select date
    , Name
    , description
from SortedResults
where RowNum = 1
```